# Import Comments from Disqus to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments, disqus, wordpress-thesis-theme

I love Disqus but it doesn't work with the current theme I'm using (Thesis 1.8) and therefore need to part ways. Does anyone know how to export my comments out of Disqus and into Wordpress? I have been unable to make this happen even after using the Disqus Comment Importer Plugin. Looks like others are having issues as well: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pl... Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the legal right to do so?

I didn't read [Disqus Terms and Policies](http://docs.disqus.com/kb/terms-and-policies/) (tl;dr) or obviously the contract you accepted when you signed in to their service, but by "importing" comments, you're in fact copying text written by others on Disqus website, not on your website!

Disqus obviously let you display these comments (that's the point of their service) but copying them, I wonder? That would be copyright infringement of author texts and/or Disqus otherwise authorized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Disqus allows you to export your comments in XML format. I just don't know how to take that file and import that into my Wordpress blog's commenting system.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Disqus myself but you said they have an export to XML.  I myself would check and see if it has a post id so you can see what post/article the comment belongs to.  IF it does (it should) then I would write a simple PHP script that will read the XML file and do the processing then add to the wordpress MySQL database